# ¿Se puede especificar el nombre de instalación en PyPI?

Tags: python, pip

acabo de subir mi primer modulo a PyPI y todo bien, pero en la homepage sale de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero que solo aparezca: **pip install DataFake**, ¿Es posible?

este es mi setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup
    
setup(name='DataFake',
    version='0.1',
    description='A python package for data fake generation',
    url='https://github.com/Josecolin99/Data-Fake',
    author='Jose Angel Colin Najera',
    author_email='josecolin99@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['datafake'],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    zip_safe=False
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eso sale porque tienes marcada la versión en la web, normalmente al entrar nos sale la última y sin especificar la versión.

Comment: podrias explicar un poco mejor como hacer eso?